# Why does this VBA code fail once I rename my Excel sheets away from the default's "Sheet1"?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Button1_Click()

   LastRow1 = LastRow("Sheet1")

End Sub

Function LastRow(sheetname as String) As Long

   LastRow = Range(sheetname & "!A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

When my sheet is named "Sheet1" my code works.  When I rename it to "Stack Overflow", it fails.  Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When my sheet is named "Sheet1" my code works. When I rename it to "Stack Overflow", it fails. Why?

That is because the latter has a space in the name.

The correct way is mentioned below which will work for both

```
Function LastRow(sheetname As String) As Long

   LastRow = Range("'" & sheetname & "'!A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

Notice the Single Quotes?

**IMP**: I know I am repeating this info but I still feel that you should follow the approach that I mentioned in the link that I gave in your last question

Comment: Just wondering if there is an advantage to this code is over `sheets(sheetname).range(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you send a sheet name string instead of the worksheet object?

```
Sub Button1_Click()

   LastRow1 = LastRow(Sheets("Sheet1"))

End Sub

Function LastRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long

   LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is in continuation to the last question :)